# Read data from URL / XML with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

this is my first question.
Im trying to learn some python, so.. i have this problem

how i can get data from this url that shows info in XML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/A23D046FC1854B18399D5383F36923E25774179C?k=5121f909fd63e674149c0e42a9847b49'
document = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(document.content, "lxml-xml")
print(soup)
```

output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdocO.png)

but i wanna get access to this type of data, < RUTEmisor> data for example:

[linkurl_invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhMb0.png)

hope guys you can try to advice me with the code and how to read xml docs.

Comment: You have prepend your url with: `http://windte1910.acepta.com/ca4webv3/XmlView?url=`, your url: `http://windte1910...` have to `urlencoded`

Comment: thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By examining the URL you gave, it seems that the data is actually held a few links away at the following URL: http://windte1910.acepta.com/depot/A23D046FC1854B18399D5383F36923E25774179C?k=5121f909fd63e674149c0e42a9847b49

As such, you can access it directly as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://windte1910.acepta.com/depot/A23D046FC1854B18399D5383F36923E25774179C?k=5121f909fd63e674149c0e42a9847b49'
document = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(document.content, "lxml-xml")

print(soup.find('RUTEmisor').text)
```

Comment: what means DEPOT in the link?? u change vo for depot

Comment: No worries. The URL with "depot" in can be seen easiest by accessing the URL via a web browser: it's the link given at the top of the page as the URL. If you're interested in how to find that link without using a web browser, it can be found via a bit of web scraping. I'd be happy to edit the solution above to show this if you're interested -- otherwise the link I gave should allow you to access the XML data if you only care about that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was looking for that answer cuz i got all this links daily so always open the links one by one to extract some info, u know how if i had this column with links on a csv read one by one on python? loops?